# XCode doesn't show all available options in autocomplete menu

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I try to set `titleTextAttributes` for `UINavigationBar.appearance()` instance. But XCode doesn't list it in autocomplete drop down list: 
[image]

However I can manually type `titleTextAttributes` and code builds successfully. What does this happen?

Comment: Just a bug with Xcode or SourceKit I guess.  I would open a radar.

Comment: http://bugreporter.apple.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what's the class of `UINavigationBar.appearance()`? It's UIAppearance — not UINavigationBar. It's a *proxy* object, not an actual navigation bar. So it has no `titleTextAttributes` property. It merely stores your commands as an invocation and then invokes that on any future *actual* navigation bars that show up in your app.

Thus, *no* UINavigationBar properties appear in the completion for `UINavigationBar.appearance()`. It's a pity, but it's not incomprehensible.

It's true that the *compiler* helps you with this by interpreting `UINavigationBar.appearance()` as if it *were* a UINavigationBar. However, that's a relatively new feature; I remember back when it didn't happen, and the compiler would just let you send *any* message to the appearance proxy (and then crash). So, it seems that this compiler feature has not been carried over into Xcode's text completion engine.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm starting to understand what is happening.

Comment: You should still file a bug report! Your expectation here is perfectly reasonable.